# AWS S3 createPresignedPost vs getSignedUrl. Which one should I use for uploading various files from client side?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, file-upload, aws-sdk

On S3 document, there is [createPresignedPost](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#createPresignedPost-property) and [getSignedUrl](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#getSignedUrl-property).

On getSignedUrl:

> Note: Not all operation parameters are supported when using pre-signed
>   URLs. Certain parameters, such as SSECustomerKey, ACL, Expires,
>   ContentLength, or Tagging must be provided as headers when sending a
>   request. If you are using pre-signed URLs to upload from a browser and
>   need to use these fields, see createPresignedPost().

Is createPresignedPost simply more customizable version of getSignedUrl?
Is it doing the same thing underneath?

Comment: According to docs, ```createPresignedPost``` is just more customizable that ```getSignedUrl```. I`d rather prefer to use ```getSignedUrl``` most of the time.

Comment: @OscarNevarez can you share link to the docs you mentioned?

Comment: @Ant100 https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#getSignedUrl-property:~:text=an%20asynchronous%20callback.-,Note%3A%20Not%20all%20operation%20parameters%20are%20supported%20when%20using%20pre%2Dsigned%20URLs.%20Certain%20parameters%2C%20such,-as%20SSECustomerKey%2C

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you want to restrict users from uploading files beyond certain size, you should be using `createPresignedPost`, and specify ContentLength

with getSignedUrl, there is no restricting object size and user can potentially upload a 5TB object (current object limit) to s3

---

Note that if you can specify ContentLength in params when calling getSignedUrl('putObject',params, callback)
you will be thrown

```
Presigning post data encountered an error { UnexpectedParameter: ContentLength is not supported in pre-signed URLs.
```

There is an [issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/1252) on this subject

Comment: I just don't understand the rationale behind `getSignedUrl`. what's the point if you can't limit your users upload file size..

Comment: can some answer this [https://stackoverflow.com/q/71004360/14580983](this). Can we validate the file type uploading through the signedURL

Comment: @ArchyWillHe何魏奇 Some developers just don't seem to care about attacks. I still don't know how rate limitting works for both of these methods and if it's available at all. It seem the same url may be used multiple times.